# Unity 4.5.5f1 shadows not appearing

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadows

I recently downloaded Unity and am working my way through a couple of the beginner projects just to get a feel for the environment. I ran into a problem, though - when I apply directional lights to the scene shadows aren't appearing. I've tried switching to hard shadows, ensuring that I don't have more than one directional light throwing shadows, ensuring that I'm using DirectX 11, forward lighting, making sure in Player options that shadows are allowed, checking the hardware specs required to run shadows in Unity - basically everything that's been suggested in other questions. Has anyone else ran into this problem? How did you fix it?

Edited: Ok, I kind of fixed it, but in a really strange way. After a bunch of searches, apparently DX11 doesn't play nice with Unity on Windows 8.1, so I've gotta use the command prompt, -force-d3d9, create a completely new project, and then uncheck the "Use DirectX 11" button.

Further update: After messing around with that for a bit, apparently if I close Unity at any point while doing this it refuses to open the project without DirectX 11 enabled, even if I force DirectX 9. If I don't force DirectX 9 and just open the project, none of the things I'd put in the scene appear. So, basically what I've discovered is that to get shadows, I've gotta create an entirely new project and then never close Unity ever at risk of losing it. Any further help is entirely welcome.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you checked Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality? It is possible to edit shadows setting there for each quality level.

Comment: Yep - I'm using the default "good" setting, which allows for hard and soft shadows. I basically just opened Unity and went straight into the Roll-a-ball tutorial to get a feel for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, switching DirextX 11 off to show shadows then Unity crashed. I opened Unity again, luckily my scene could be restored, but DirextX 11 still stayed enabled.
What I did was just hid "Scene" and "Game" panes by showing other panes ("Animator" and "Console", to be precise) so that any graphics wouldn't be refreshed on screen when I switched DirectX 11 on/off. Doing so, Unity didn't crash, but as soon as I displayed "Scene" pane, Unity crashed immediately. So without displaying graphics I saved my scene/project, closed Unity, and opened it again then I could edit my scene with DX11 disabled.
Well, this might be a voodoo thing, but just for sharing my solution.